# Which is the workspace server path in Visual Studio to access a remote SQL Server Analysis server?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssas

I am able to access a remote SQL Server Analysis server through SSMS with the following command:

```
runas /netonly /user:lua\sqladmin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\ssms"
```

And it opens fine:

[image]

But how can I access it in Visual Studio?

I tried like this:

[image]

But I've had no success.

Comment: Are you using `Visual Studio` or `Visual Studio Code`? Those are two entirely different products.

Comment: Sorry, is Visual Studio. I am editing my question.

Comment: Did you try launching Visual Studio using `runas /netonly` ?